# Detection of type by passing in constructor works inconsistently

Tags: typescript

I'm having a "WTF" moment. I have a type modeling system that leverages Typescript systax for not only design-time typing but also run-time. The details of aren't terribly important but basically you define a "model" like so:

```
@model({ dbOffset: "authenticated" })
export class Person extends Model {
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @length(20) public name: string;
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @min(1) @max(100) public age?: number;
  @property public gender?: "male" | "female" | "other";
  @property public scratchpad?: IDictionary;
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @pushKey public tags?: IDictionary<string>;

  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public motherId?: fk;
  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public fatherId?: fk;
  // prettier-ignore
  @hasMany(Person) public children?: IDictionary;

  @ownedBy(Company) public employerId?: fk;
}
```

With this instances of the **Person** class get a `META` property which allows for run-time introspection of their properties.

I've used this **Person** class for a lot of my tests and to my shock and horror today when I created the **FancyPerson** I found it is behaving differently in a way that is totally perplexing. Here's the FancyPerson:

```
@model({ dbOffset: "authenticated" })
export class FancyPerson extends Model {
  @property public name: string;
  @property public age: number;
  @property public phoneNumber: string;
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @mock("phoneNumber") public otherPhone: string;
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @mock(bespokeMock) public foobar: string;
  @ownedBy(Company) public employer: fk;
  @hasMany(Car) public cars: fk[];
}
```

Now when add a new **Record** as you see below, I get a Typescript error with **FancyPerson** but not **Person**. The error is

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '{ name: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Model'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Model'.

[image]

[image]

Ok so here's the problem ... BOTH **Person** and **FancyPerson** have the property `name` but for some reason when I pass in **FancyPerson** it doesn't implicitly type it as **FancyPerson** but instead as just default value of **Model** (which indeed does *not* have the `name` property).

Here is the Record's static add method and I guess possibly the source of the problem:

```
public static async add<T extends Model>(
  model: new () => T,
  payload: T,
  options: IRecordOptions = {}
) {
  let r;
  try {
    r = Record.create(model, options);
    console.log(r.modelName, r.META.dbOffset);

    r._initialize(payload);
    await r._save();
  } catch (e) {
    const err = new Error(`Problem adding new Record: ${e.message}`);
    err.name = e.name !== "Error" ? e.name : "FireModel";
    throw e;
  }

  return r;
}
```

Still if this *is* the source of the problem I can't see how it works with `People` but not `FancyPeople`. Please someone rescue from the madness.

---

## Update

I have been madly playing with the properties in the various models to understand what could possibly switch the `Record.add()` function to and away from recognizing the constructor being passed in ...

Here's what I've just found, if at least one property within the model class is *not*-required then `Record.add()` recognizes the class implicitly but if all properties are required then it falls back to the default of `Model` (which is not good at all for what I'm doing).

This behavior is very reproducible but I have no idea *why* it is as it is. Feels like a bug.

Comment: Could you trim that down into something that compiles as-is without dependencies on other code or libraries?  (e.g., something that would work on [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/))  So, no decorators unless they affect the issue you're seeing (and then include their definitions), etc.  If it takes a bunch of work just to reproduce what you're seeing, it makes it less likely that someone will have a helpful answer for you.

Comment: I will try but I have a strong feeling it IS related to the decorators.